# Complex Query using CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table which has data like,

```
Date            Custid  CreditDebit     Units   Value
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   1   10
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   2   11
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   1   12
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   2   13
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       D   1   20
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       D   2   21
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   1   20
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   2   21
```

I need to get a temp table output as follow,

```
Date            Custid  CreditDebit     Units   Value Balance
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       C   1   42      42-20
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       c   2   45      22+45-21
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       D   1   20      ---
2013-03-29 06:21:46.903     1       D   2   21      ---
```

That is sum of the Value column which is based on 'CreditDebit' and Units.
How can i achieve this using CTE sql Query

Comment: Why the CTE stipulation? Does seem somewhat arbitrary as it is not required in any way. Also please choose a better title. This is not remotely complex. `GROUP BY` is something you would learn in any introductory SQL text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH summary_table_cte
     AS (SELECT Date,
                Custid,
                CreditDebit,
                Units,
                sum(value) AS [Value]
         FROM   YourTable
         GROUP  BY Date,
                   Custid,
                   CreditDebit,
                   Units)
SELECT *
FROM   summary_table_cte;
```

Note the semi-colon at the start of the statement. A statement preceding a CTE must be terminated with a semi-colon. By prefixing `WITH` with it, you can put it anywhere.

Comment: hmm.. i need to add up all the rows of the column [Value]. Its not doing that..:-(

Comment: @Tanya - This answers the question you asked. For your example source data this returns your desired results. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4956a/5)

Comment: @NareshPansuriya - This query **does** return her stated desired results from stated input data. If it turns out she missed something in the explanation then she should ask a new question not change this one to ask something different.

Comment: @NareshPansuriya - See the SQL Fiddle link im my earlier comment.

Comment: @Tanya, is display result match with Duncan Howe result? if no then what is the problem?

Comment: My problem is i need one more column name Balance in which i need the values (C-D) in the first rows and the next row should be (Balance + C-D). I'm using the CTE in which how can i control every iteration?

Comment: This CTE works fine with some changes which i made to get my result..  Thank you..